# Why I cant duplicate data to this table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have a table called "rma_device_list" and it is a relational table so there is no primary key nor unique key. It should allow me to insert duplicate data but it doesn't. It says I cant insert duplicate data.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf3X5.png) of my table:

Here is the insert query I am executing: `INSERT INTO rma_device_list(rma_id, device_id, dev_comment, manuf_comment) VALUES (0,1298,"sdfsdf","sdfsdfdsfds")`

Comment: Single quotes vs double quotes

Comment: Your screenshot certainly looks like your table has a unique key.

Comment: On the contrary, it looks like the table has a composite PK. The error is clear - that key combination already exists. That `0` for `rma_id` is rather suspicious - is your code using `0` as a default ID value? This means that "missing" `ID` values are stored with a concrete `0`. If you try to store two such rows with the same `device_id` you'll get a duplicate error

Comment: it looks like you are having unique index on rma_id, device_id

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the rma_id is the ID I take from another table however in some cases there is no ID from that table so I just insert 0 in the table shown above.

Comment: @VenkataramanR how can I actually remove them because I didnt see any option to remove unique key

Comment: That screen shot is clearly PHPMyAdmin, which has nothing to do with SQL Server and is *normally* used as an interface for MySQL. What RDBMS are you *raelly* using? The lack of an error in your post doesn't help us debug this either, however, the **columns** `sdfsdf` and `sdfsdfdsfds` will have no context in your `VALUES` clause.

Comment: @biciklla which means you'll get duplicate keys. 0 is a *concrete* ID. If some value is missing, use NULL. That's how SQL works.

Comment: @Larnu how can I remove unique/primary keys, I tried to find an option to remove but couldn't.

Comment: @biciklla you don't - your code and logic have a flow that needs to be fixed. The Unique constraint is *not* a problem, storing 0 instead of NULL, or trying to store duplicate keys is the real problem

Comment: *"how can I remove unique/primary keys"* That depends on your RDBMS; which we don't know, @biciklla. PHPMyAdmin and SQL Server do not mix so one of those tags was wrong.

Comment: What is the *business logic* when `rma_id` is missing? What kind of records so you want to store in this case? And how would you be able to tell one from another? Can you have multiple comments when `rma_id`is unknown? If you do, perhaps you *shouldn't* be using that table at all, but a separate `Device_Comments` table

Comment: After all, those comments refer to the relation of `rma` and `device`. When there's no RMA, what's the point of commenting on that RMA? Device comments should go to their own table.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes I can have multiple rows with rma_id=0 and they can all have same `device_id` as well.

Comment: @biciklla what's the point? Those are device comments. They should go to their own table

Comment: This sounds like the we're going to a filtered unique index route.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos most of the RMA id will refer to the other table where more data can be found about that RMA however whenever this table contains rma_id=0 it means there is not RMA related to that so i display it somewhere else.

Comment: @Larnu what do you mean?

Comment: It's a Unque Index, that's filtered, @biciklla . It does what it says on the tin. But considering you've still not responded to my question of what RDBMS you are *really* using...

Comment: @biciklla so *store* it somewhere else too. Databases and tables aren't files. A *table* defines a relation between its fields. If you have *any* row that has no relation to the `rma_id` field, it has no business being stored in that table. It means the table is misused to store two *different* entities

Comment: @biciklla the reason that Larnu insists on knowing what the actual database is, is that some databases (like SQL Server) have ways of applying indexes and UNIQUE constraints to only a subset of the rows. In this case though, you have a plain old design bug - just use a proper table for standalone device comments. You gain nothing by trying to use the same table to store different types of data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need them in this table because later I count how my RMA has a specific device. That's why I kept the rows with rma_id=0 there.

Comment: @biciklla you're counting devices from the *comments*? Even so, this means you *can't* have a `0` RMA_ID - otherwise you won't know which RMA you're looking for. Unless you meant you want to find if your device has RMAs?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos when counting I am fetching all rows that contain device_id=? and then counting how many are there.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am totally confused why those two are set as primary keys because as you can see the "Primary" key is clickable right now, meaning that if I click on it THEN it will make set them as Primary keys.

Comment: @biciklla you don't need to store a `0` in that case at all. Just do an INNER JOIN between `devices` and `rma_devices_list` and count the number of `rma_id`s in `rma_devices_list`. If you want to include devices without RMAs, use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @biciklla it's your database - you should explain the reasoning. As for the PK - they aren't, but they *do* have a UNIQUE constraint. Again though, that's irrelevant. You shouldn't be using a many-to-many table when there's *no* relation to record

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I MUST keep them there, I can't have them with another rma_id and I can't have them stored in another table. It's out of discussion moving them somewhere else. Again, its VERY RELEVANT how to remove that constraint from those two columns!

Comment: You're asking how to cover up the bug, not how to fix it. Which database are you using? Different databases have different features. SQL Server has filtered indexes. MySQL may have another feature for this. Or, if you really don't want that UNIQUE constraint, remove it

Comment: Are you asking how to use phpAdmin to remove constraints perhaps? There are duplicate questions for this, but you should probably *not* use a web administration tool to edit your database, and certainly not in production.

Answer (score 2):

According to your screen shot, the combination of `rma_id` and `device_id` is unique.  Hence, you cannot insert duplicate pairs into the table.  That is what the error message is telling you.

In fact, the columns also don't have `NULL` values, so you might as well declare the pair as the primary key.

Comment: how can I actually undo unique key for both?

Comment: You can drop the unique constraint or index.  You can also recreate the table to have the format you really want.